# Can I use Adaptive Payments in Android?

Tags: android, paypal

I've been looking at Paypal Adaptive Payments for a while and can't seem to be able to figure out how to use it in Android. I want to let the user of my app cash out their points for PayPal money. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can see this link

Visit http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-integrating-paypal-using-php-mysql-part-2/!

Comment: That doesn't support Adaptive Payments...    :(

Comment: Help??. PLease I'm really stuck